# can't loop over array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, tags, jquery-select2

Hey guys i ned to know how to loop over an array in javascript i used many times php and i know how to over an array with foreach but i dont know how to use it with js, i'm trying to set some selected tags in a select input
here's the foreach

```
montant.forEach(element => {
      $('#montant').empty()
           .append('<option value="'+element.id+'">'+element.designation+'</option>')
           .val(''+element.id+'').trigger('change')});
```

montant is a value who contains an array with those elements

```
const montant = [
  {designation: 120000, id: 11},
  {designation: 30000, id: 12},
  {designation: 40000, id: 13}
]
```

with the foreach that i used i just get the first element

Comment: Could you include the actual Structre of `montant` - Your example makes it seem like perhaps you're using an Object instead

Comment: when console.log(montant) i get this array
`(3) […]
​
0: Object { id: 11, designation: 120000 }
​
1: Object { id: 12, designation: 30000 }
​
2: Object { id: 13, designation: 40000 }
​
length: 3`

Comment: You're calling `empty()` on the element in every iteration of the loop, so only the final value will be shown. Remove `empty()`

Answer (score 4):

If `montant` is an array, then you're doing it right by using `forEach`. However, for each iteration of the loop, you are doing this:

```
$('#montant').empty().append(...)
```

So, for each item, you're emptying `#montant` (which I assume is a `select`), so, in the end, your select only has one `option`, the last one.

I think you must use `empty()` *before* the loop, and `trigger` afterwards, so the event handler doesn't get called for each item of the array:

```
const $montant = $('#montant');
$montant.empty()
montant.forEach(element => $montant.append(...));
$montant.trigger('change');
```

Now, your `select` should be correctly populated.

Comment: same problem i get the last element of the array :/